# Making a normal map work in bge

Tags: game-engine, normal-map

[image: when I play the game]When I put a normal map on my object the object looks fine. But in play mode it shows the normal map as a texture.

[image: when I render]

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. Include images of the issue and your current settings.

Comment: Are you in multitexture mode? Try changing to GLSL mode.